# How to dynamically spawn images in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm not new to coding; but I haven't worked much in WPF. What I'm trying to do is spawn and move images from an array so that the result looks something like this:

[Example of what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92ckn.gif)

In Unity I'd use the [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) method, then move the transform position around via c# code. However, I'm not sure how to tackle this in WPF.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in WPF for this specific case (which don't require performance strictly), you can use `Path` (a Shape in WPF) which can be rendered from a `Geometry` and moved around on a `Canvas`. That's all you need to get started. For much better performance (rendering a lot of objects) of course we should not use `Shape` and instead draw everything directly on a `DrawingVisual` but I think it's hard to manage the objects yourself, using `Shape` should always work fine in almost cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StoryBoard` with `DoubleAnimation` to achieve this.

Please check below code.

```
<Window x:Class="ImageAnimation.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImageAnimation"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard" BeginTime="00:00:00.000" Duration="00:00:1.000">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RotateImage" 
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" 
                             From="50" To="100" BeginTime="00:00:00.000" Duration="00:00:00.200" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RotateImage" 
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" 
                             From="100" To="90" BeginTime="00:00:00.000" Duration="00:00:00.100" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RotateImage" 
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" 
                             From="90" To="100" BeginTime="00:00:00.050" Duration="00:00:00.100" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OpacityImage" 
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" 
                             From="100" To="50" BeginTime="00:00:00.000" Duration="00:00:00.200" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OpacityImage" 
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" 
                             From="100" To="110" BeginTime="00:00:00.000" Duration="00:00:00.100" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OpacityImage" 
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" 
                             From="110" To="100" BeginTime="00:00:00.050" Duration="00:00:00.100" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Image x:Name="RotateImage" Stretch="Uniform" Source="1.png" Height="50" Width="50" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="100">

            </Image>
            <Image x:Name="OpacityImage" Grid.Column="1" Stretch="Uniform" Source="2.png" Height="50" Width="50" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100"/>
        </Canvas>

        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Start">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard}" />
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```